# Apache Kylin : running under windows 7

Tags: apache, kylin

I have looked all over the net, and could not really find anything on running Apache Kylin in Windows 7.
Another approach is using Docker, but would i be able to run Docker under windows 7.

Hope someone can let me know if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

As almost all user are running Hadoop on Linux, and Kylin need to be deployed on a Hadoop node, so Kylin didn't provide a non-Linux startup script.

In theory, Kylin can run on Windows as it is a Java (tomcat) application.

Could you please share your scenario of running Kylin on Windows?

Comment: Hi, its not about any particular scenario. I want to always be able to install software on both platforms, the 2 platforms I am interested in are Linux/Ubuntu and Windows OS.

Comment: I see; We only start Kylin on Windows in IntelliJ IDEA for development, that works well. Haven't seen production deployment on Windows.